# Embed plotly interactive figure in github-pages markdown

Tags: html, plotly, markdown, embed, github-pages

I want to build a site using github pages and I'm having issues as I'm currently trying to embed the following interactive plot in my markdown file ([map obtained using plotly.express.choropleth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS6Rv.png)). I've tried multiple options already, such as saving my figure into an html file and then trying to add the html file to my markdown file with the following options :

```
- {% include_relative figure.html %}
- {% include figure.html %}
- <embed type="text/html" src="figure.html" width="600" height="400"></embed>
- <iframe>
- <object>
- <div>
```

None of these lines ended up with my figure showing up on the markdown file. I might be using them wrong as I'm not the most familiar with this, but I hope someone can find what I've been doing wrong or how to tackle this issue.

If it is of any use, here is the code for the figure I'm trying to display and how I save it :

```
fig = px.choropleth(feat_df, geojson=counties, locations='id', color='hurr_tot',
                           color_continuous_scale="viridis",
                           range_color=(0, 40), center = {"lat": 38, "lon": -100},
                           scope="usa",
                           hover_name="county", hover_data=['code','hurr_tot'],
                           labels={'hurr_tot':'Hurricanes'}
                          )
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate="County : %{hovertext} <br>State : %{customdata[0]}, <br>Hurricanes : %{customdata[1]}")
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0}, width=650, height=400, newshape_line_color='#000000')

fig.show()
pio.write_html(fig, file='figure.html')
```

Here is my html file :

```
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /></head>
<body>
    <div>                        <script type="text/javascript">window.PlotlyConfig = {MathJaxConfig: 'local'};</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">/**

!function(t){if("object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module)module.exports=t();else if("function"==typeof define&&define.amd)define([],t);else{("undefined"!=typeof window?window:"undefined"!=typeof global?global:" ...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `{% include %}` isn't Markdown. Are you using something like Jekyll with GitHub Pages?

Comment: I'd rather not, but I have it all setup, so if it is necessary I can switch to using Jekyll

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out _what_ you're trying to deploy to GitHub Pages. Are you using any other static site framework? Plain HTML?

Comment: Basically, I'm asked to do a data analysis for a project on github-pages, and most of my analysis is based on my interactive plots as described before. For the moment, I'm just trying to pick the right framework so that I'll be able to incorporate those graphs. Right now, I simply have one _config.yml file and an index.md file containing the text of my analysis. Is there any way to embed those graphs in my .md file directly ? It's just a lot easier for me as I have to move forward to stay with markdown as it is very user-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to tell you that inserting interactive plots is not possible in 'raw' README.md GitHub. Luckily, there is another GitHub alternative for this: **GitHub Pages**. Here I attach a quite [good tutorial](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/2016/Lesson5-share-on-github.html) about how to easily prepare your repository to obtain a webpage to load your interactive plots and to navigate through all the interactive plots that you save in your repository.

Hope it helps you! Happy plotting!